# What is PHP's pendant to pythons encode('hex')?

Tags: php, python

In python you can encode a string as

```
encoded = text.encode('hex')
text = encoded.decode('hex')
```

What are the corresponding functions in php?

Comment: Could you describe what `encode` does in Python?

Comment: it converts the string of text into a hex value, and decode reverse it

Answer (score 3):

you can use

```
$data = bin2hex("your string");
$string = hex2bin($data);
```

or

```
$data = implode('', unpack("H*", "your string"));
$string = pack("H*", $data);
```

Comment: `pack`/`unpack` can be used but not like this. And please run the code if you are not sure, it si still wrong.

Comment: Not only. To convert string to hex representation you should use `unpack`. And to be compatible with python, high nibble first should be used.